# std::sort() C++ not working but its so simple, why :( 1D array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, std

This should be really simple, I have found that the first argument is the array name, the second is the size of the array + array name. However, it doesnt seem to be sorting at all, in fact its not doing anything, well not writing anything on the console, am I doing somethin silly?

```
int main()
{
    readFromFile();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void readFromFile()
{
    string line;
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    ifstream file("ACW2_data.txt");

if(file.is_open())
{
    getline(file, line);

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file >> numbers[i];
        i++;
        int elements = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
        **sort(numbers, numbers + elements);**
    }
    file.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "Cant open the file" << endl;
}

for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    cout << numbers[j] << endl;
}

system("pause");
}
```

what do you guys think?

Comment: What is the type of `numbers`?

Comment: What does your file look like?

Comment: Is `numbers` a pointer? How is it allocated? And why are you sorting after each number read instead of just reading them all first and then sorting them afterwards?

Comment: When asking you should be clear on the core of the question. In this case, since the question is around the call to `sort( numbers, numbers+elements )` you should provide what `numbers` and `elements` are. How the data is read or written to the console is much less relevant than the actual line that is failing. --BTW, is `numbers` a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (!file.eof())
{
    file >> numbers[i];
    i++;
    int elements = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
    **sort(numbers, numbers + elements);**
}
file.close();
```

to

```
while (file >> numbers[i])
{
    ++i;
}
sort( numbers, numbers + i );
file.close();
```

or

```
std::vector<your_int_type> numbers;
your_int_type tmp;
while (file >> tmp)
{
    numbers.push_back(tmp);
}
std::sort( numbers.begin(), numbers.end() );
file.close();
```

Comment: looks right, you should be adding the number of elements to the beginning of the array, not its size in bytes

Comment: omg thank you, im so stupid recently and im a beginner. i put the elements one in cos it wasnt workin, forgot to change it back to "i" lol thank you again!

Comment: Please fix `while (!file.eof())`

Comment: The while loop should look like: `while(file >> tmp)`

Answer (score 2):

Edit: For the moment, I'm assuming `numbers` was an array of int. If not, well, I'll hope you can figure out what to do...

```
int main() { 
    std::ifstream file("ACW2_data.txt");

    std::vector<int> numbers;

    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(file),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(numbers));

    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` ?

Comment: @Cubbi: Yes - I was lazy, but I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

First, where is `numbers` defined, and what is its type?

Second, the number of elements in `numbers` is `i` at every iteration of the while loop, so you do not need to calculate it.

Third, why are you sorting `numbers` every time you insert a new element?  Why not insert all the elements, and then sort once.  After the while loop that is.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess, since you are not showing the important detail of how `numbers` is declared, is that it is a pointer, and the `sizeof` trick is failing to calculate the allocated size. It is better to use a template based sizeof like:

```
template <typename T, int N>
int array_size( T (&)[N] ) {
   return N;
}
```

or:

```
template <typename T, int N>
char (&array_size_impl( T(&)[N] ))[N];
#define ARRAY_SIZE( x ) sizeof( array_size_impl( x ) )
```

As those will trigger compile time errors if a pointer is used, instead of silently failing and yielding unexpected results as the `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` trick.